# Firebase Realtime Database - orderByChild().equalsTo() returns Parent key in snapshot instead of value matched

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Users Collection]

This is how my users collection looks like. I am trying to fetch child which matches with **+911234567890** and here's my code for the same:

```
mDatabase.child(Commons.DB_USER).orderByChild(Commons.CHILD_CONTACT).equalTo('+911234567890').addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                                UserModel user = snapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);
                                Utils.debug("Children onDataChange " + snapshot.getChildrenCount() + " " +  user.getName() + " " + snapshot.getKey());

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                            }
                        });
```

I am expecting that I will get the Usermodel in the snapshot matching the key I passed. However, accessing name within Usermodel gives null and snapshot.getKey() returns **users**

How do I get the object under the key **+911234567890**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Your `onDataChange` needs to handle this list, by looping over the `snapshot.getChildren()`. So:

```
mDatabase.child(Commons.DB_USER).orderByChild(Commons.CHILD_CONTACT).equalTo('+911234567890').addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            UserModel user = userSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);
            Utils.debug("Children onDataChange " + snapshot.getChildrenCount() + " " +  user.getName() + " " + userSnapshot.getKey());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though I found the solution with Frank's answer, I tried a few more ways and finally got this:

```
mDatabase.child(Commons.DB_USER).orderByKey().equalTo(child).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                        if (snapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
                            UserModel user = snapshot.child(child).getValue(UserModel.class);
                            Utils.debug("Children onDataChange " + snapshot.getChildrenCount() + " " + user.getName());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                        Utils.debug("Children onCancelled " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                });
```

What this does here is, when the condition matches and you are expecting EXACTLY ONE result, then you can directly use it as a path to access the inner child/object without writing a for loop.

```
(snapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) will take care of condition not satisfying any result.
```

Comment: If you already know the key of the child node you want to read, you don't need a query or a loop at all. You can do `mDatabase.child(Commons.DB_USER).child(child).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {` and then in there just `snapshot.getValue(UserModel.class)`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen But what if the child doesn't exists, wont this fail?

Comment: Nope. It will just give you an empty snapshot, which you can catch with `if (snapshot.exists()) {` just like you now do `public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {`.